# Windows phone 8.1 only one tile

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to create an app from the blank app 8.1 runtime template.  for my app i only wish to use the standard tile size, how to I remove the other two from the package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your Package.appxmanifest in Visual Studio's manifest editor (double click the appxmanifest in the Solution Explorer), go to the Visual Assets tab, select the wide tile, and push the cancel X on the path textbox to clear it.